# Stempel Polish Analysis Plugin as plugin to Elasticsearch doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, lexical-analysis, elasticsearch-plugin

Belowe example it has been invoked on es 2.3 and 1.7.

At first I installed plugin: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-stempel.html#analysis-stempel

Next my step was check correctly installed plugin:
Result on my screen:

```
Installed plugins in /home/adam/Desktop/elasticsearch-2.3.0/plugins:
- analysis-stempel
- marvel-agent
- license
```

Next I added mapping for blog:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/my_index -d '{ 
 "mappings": {
    "blog": {
      "properties": {
        "title": { 
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "polish": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "polish"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Then I added document:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/my_index/blog/1 -d
'{ "title": "Bardzo kocham zółwie"}'
```

When I used:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_search -d
'{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type":     "most_fields", 
      "query":    "zółwie",
      "fields": [ "title", "title.polish" ]
    }
  }
}
'
```

Elasticsearch returns correct result but if I put:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_search -d
'{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type":     "most_fields", 
      "query":    "zolwie",
      "fields": [ "title", "title.polish" ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Elasticsearch nothing returns.

Problem is with polish special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need for the second query is [`asciifolding` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/asciifolding-token-filter.html#asciifolding-token-filter). I would suggest the following mapping, to cover more use cases:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "folding": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "blog": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "folding": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "folding"
            },
            "polish": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "polish"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type": "most_fields",
      "query": "zolwie",
      "fields": [
        "title.*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```